# How to divide and split one number into 7 different cells in another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to break apart a single number of deliveries (eg. 180) in a week into a daily value grouped by location. 180/7 put into a 7 rows and tied to the location of the 180. I have tried to research this but all of my searches bring me to the split function which does not seem to fit my needs. Array(if( is great for the grouping but it does not split to multiple cells.

```
ARRAYFORMULA(if(BinCountData!A3:A,"Clarksville",)), BinCountData!A3:D;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((A1/7)*ROW(1:7)^0)
```

[image]

if it needs to be rounded use `ROUNDUP` or `ROUNDDOWN`

Comment: That is very helpful and exactly what I needed, thank you